# Log4j Logger Name Attribute Setting

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j

Is it possible to set the logger name attribute as a regular expression or ant pattern in log4j?

for example

```
<logger name="com.sample.test..domain" additivity="false">
    <level value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</logger>
```

or

```
<logger name="com.sample.test.*.domain" additivity="false">
    <level value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about ant patterns but in your example, if you use the following...

```xml
<logger name="com.sample.test" additivity="false">
    <level value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</logger>
```

...it will log everything within the com.sample.test package as well as everything below that in the package hierarchy. So that will log for com.sample.test.domain, even if the domain package floats around.

Not an exact answer to your question but it may be useful.